# Marketing Cloud SDK 8.0.3 crash

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I'm using `com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.0.3` and I have the following crash in some devices:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
 at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance (Unknown Source:13)
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're not initializing the SDK in your application's `onCreate()` method and/or you're delaying/preventing the SDK from being initialized.

Also, if you're application is calling `getInstance()` I would suggest refactoring it to use `requestSdk()`.

````
@Nullable @MCKeep public static MarketingCloudSdk getInstance() {
    if (!isInitializing && !isReady) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          "MarketingCloudSdk#init must be called before calling MarketingCloudSdk#getInstance.");
    }```
````

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I checked it and I',m initializing the SDK in my app's `onCreate()` method 
just like with the version 7, but I didn't have this crash with version 7.  And, about using `requestSdk()` instead of `getInstance()`, is there a link with more info about it? I just did theese migration steps: [SFMCSdk Migration](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/get-started-migration.html)

Comment: `getInstance()` is a blocking call and discouraged.

Comment: If you need further assistance you should open a support ticket through your account manager.